# Connect dell U2419H with macbook pro

Tags: multiple-monitors, macbook

I have a MacBook Pro (13-inch, 2017, Two Thunderbolt 3 ports) and I recently purchase a dell U2419H Ultrasharp monitor to connect the laptop with. The monitor works properly and the resolution is quite good (in case of images). However, I got a bit issue with blurry fonts that make the usage bit annoying.

Is there a way to overcome this issue? I have tried to far are the recommendation [I found here](https://medium.com/@nvucuong/macos-blurry-texts-on-an-external-full-hd-monitor-d2a955c25607), but still did not work. Any recommends?

Comment: You're used to looking at a retina screen, that's 2560x1600 in a mere 13" display. You now have a monitor which by comparison has pixels the size of dinner plates. You will never get it sharp. It's not capable. "Full HD" is a mere 1920x1080, that really was never enough for a 24" screen.

Comment: So what is the requirement? For example, if I buy a 2560x1600 of 24 or bigger is it going to work?

Comment: You need 227 PPI, which at 24" is more than a 4k, nearer a 5k. 2560x1600 [approx 2k] is only 227 PPI on a 13" screen. See https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/309021/what-external-monitor-to-buy-that-has-same-clarity-as-the-macbook